# How to use Python beautifulsoup for websites with Download button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, mechanize

I was wondering if there's a way I could download attachments from a webpage which doesn't have an explicit link to it using beautifulsoup or other Python modules(mechanize, urllib2)?

For example, in the following website
http://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236,
we need to first choose some options and then hit the download button to download the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (a package used to control a browser with code).

Comment: Thank you. Selenium and chromedriver work perfectly for me !

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the download button is submitting a post request with some form data and giving you the result as a download. Try submitting the form using python requests library and process the download.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/